# GridView with variable sized widgets?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create a GridView that has the ability to handle variable sized widgets; exactly as the HTC Sense homescreen does. Does anyone know of any source reference or tutorials for such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class CellLayout in the AOSP Launcher2 code is used to do this.

Comment: AedonEtLIRA, while I appreciate your effort to add a relevant link to this answer, the version of this file you linked to is not in a repository controlled by AOSP. Instructions for obtaining the canonical version are here: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Answer (score 0):

A tableLayout seems more appropriate than a GridView. GridView is more about displaying a grid of items that have the same shape.

Comment: This will allow you to have a widget traverse multiple rows?

Comment: I also need to move widgets around, as the homescreen does. The TableLayout is not optimal for that.